# Spring AOP around rest exucution

Tags: spring, rest, aop, aspectj

I have a small piece of code. 
Rest controller

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {
    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting() {
        return "greeting";
    }
}
```

and aspect

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class Audience {
@Around("execution(** com.fire.example.GreetingController.greeting(..))")
    public void silenceCellPhones(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Before call");
            jp.proceed();
            System.out.println("After call");
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And I don't know why, but rest controller works well without aspect and doesn't work with it. In case of using @After and @Before rest also works well. When I say rest doesn't work I mean there is no response returned. 
I would appreciate any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An around advice has to return (as Object) the result of the .proceed()-method or you are removing the return value.

Comment: thank you very much, I didn't know about that. Now it works perfectly